# How to limit an association list based on a related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, associations

I know that I should know this, but I cannot seem to figure it out at all and I'm still new to development...

So I have four models...

Appointments

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :profile
    belongs_to :location
end
```

Profiles

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :appointments

    has_many :profile_locations
    has_many :locations, through: :profile_locations
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile_locations, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

end
```

profile_locations

```
class ProfileLocation < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :profile
    belongs_to :location
    belongs_to :location_type

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :location

end
```

and locations

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :profile_locations
    has_many :profiles, through: :profile_locations

    has_many :appointments

end
```

On the create appointments page, I already have an associated profile on the record.  I also have an association field on my simple_form for locations that I want to be able to assign to the appointment based on those tied to the profile..

I was trying something like this, but cannot seem to getting working.

```
%td= f.association :location, :as => :collection_select, collection: Location.where( location.profile_location.profile_id: @profile.id ), label_method: :address_1, value_method: :id, include_blank: false, :input_html => {:class => "input-small"}, :label => "Select The Location"
```

Am I missing something here or is there an easier way to query this?  Any guidance on any of this would be helpful.

Comment: can you explain it in more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks ksarunas....   I needed a minor tweak, but got it running!

```
%td= f.association :location, :as => :collection_select, collection: Location.includes(:profile_locations).where(profile_locations: { profile_id: @appointment.profile_id })
```

Was getting an error trying to pull in the @profile.id and had to pluralize the profile_locationS in both places.

Answer (score 0):

If you are are using `simple_form` you should be creating `collection_input` like this:

```
%td= f.input :location, collection: Location.joins(:profile_location).where(profile_locations: { profile_id: @profile.id })
```

Comment: This piece is where it doesn't seem to be pulling it as expected:

    Location.where( location.profile_location.profile_id: @profile.id )

Is that the correct syntax for that type of filter based on the active profile?

Comment: Ohh yes. I just copy/pasted your query. It is wrong. You need to join `profile_locations`. Thus it would be: `Location.joins(:profile_location).where(profile_locations: { profile_id: @profile.id })`. Updated answer with correct query